# MySQL / MariaDB order by with mixed data types

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I have a table (variable_value) where I save a mix of data types in one text column (value). The table looks like this:

```
value: text
type: char(36)
entity_id: char(36)
```

I want to be able to sort on the value column with numerical, date and text values ordered correctly. To do this I use the "type" column to cast the value into the correct type using a case statement, a simple example would be to cast to DECIMAL and DATE depending on type:

```
SELECT `value`, `type` FROM variable_value ORDER BY IF(`type` = "numeric", CAST(`value` as DECIMAL), IF(`type` = "date", CAST(`value` as DATE), `value`))
```

The result I get is this:

```
*value*             *type*
1                   numeric
1                   numeric
10000               numeric
2012-01-01 00:00:00 date
2012-03-23 00:00:00 date
2012-05-08          date
2012-05-18 00:00:00 date
3                   numeric
5                   numeric
```

What I want is something that at least puts the numeric values in the correct order. I do not care so much if different types are mixed up in the result, but as you can see 3 is sorted after 10000. I have tried to sort on type then the casted value but that does not work either.

Does any one have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the values.  MySQL supports implicit type conversion, which is very helpful in this case:

```
order by (case when type = 'numeric' then value + 0 end)
```

This orders the numerics, giving a `NULL` value to everything else.

Perhaps a more orderly solution is:

```
order by type,
         (case when type = 'numeric' then value + 0 end),
         (case when type = 'date' then date(value) end),
         value
```